# Merging development branch into Pull Request branch brings extra commits into Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I have a development branch [hood-devel](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow/tree/hood-devel) in my fork which is 1 commit ahead of original master [tensorflow/master](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), and a pull request branch [hood](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow/tree/hood) where the pull request into tensorflow/master lives.

I did the following set of commands to merge hood-devel into hood, and it brought in commits from tensorflow/master into my [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2747). Any idea why this is happening, and the best way to undo this?

```
git checkout hood-devel
git merge -s ours hood
git checkout hood
git merge hood-devel
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that "Pull Request" will automatically include commits that happened after first Pull Request commit every time you do change like merge. The solution is to rebase to head.

IE, to rebase to head by overwriting all conflicts with versions in my branch

```
git checkout $mybranch
git remote add tfmain https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
git fetch --all
export merge_root=`git merge-base $mybranch tfmain/master`
git rebase -i $merge_root
git rebase -Xtheirs tfmain/master
```

Comment: Or just use a dedicated temporary branch for pending pull requests

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have dedicated branch "hood" which I requested to merge into tensorflow/master. The problem is that when I do some change to "hood" like merging from another branch, my pull request gets polluted with commits that happened in tensorflow/master in the intervening time

Comment: Checkout hood, then make a new branch, say `hoodPR`  initiate pull request. Keep developing on hood. Don't touch hoodPR. When pull request is complete, delete hoodPR

Comment: I see. I guess that doesn't work for something like tensorflow project because there are issues that come up during review that need to be addressed before PR is merged, so PR needs to be modified